# Dell PowerVault TL1000 Tape Library RHEL 8 Connectivity

Tags: rhel8

I have a Dell PowerVault TL1000 Tape Library which I've connected to our Dell PowerEdge R740xd Rack Server through a Dell HBA355e Adapter. The server is running RHEL 8 under ESXi 7.0.3

I did the `lspci` command in RHEL and the tape library is nowhere to be found in spite of being listed on ESXi as `vmhba5` with hardware status displayed as `unknown`.  I've tried enabling passthough with no success.

This Tape Library is new and is running well on a Dell PowerEdge R440 Rack Server connected through the Dell HBA355e Adapter running Windows Server 2019 Standard and Veeam.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You may install Starwinds tape redirector on the Windows host with a tape library. Tape redirector is able to share it over iSCSI into the RHEL VM. The job is done :) https://www.starwindsoftware.com/download-starwind-tape-redirector

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the root cause of your issue, but  according to [KB 1016407](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1016407) and [KB 2007904](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2007904) , VMware no longer supports Tape Drives connected directly to ESXi 5.x and later.